# Haskell Parser not working

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am trying to understand Parsers. Therefore I have created my own parser. Unfortunately it does not work. Why?

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

preturn :: a -> Parser a 
preturn t = \inp -> [(t,inp)] 

pfailure :: Parser a 
pfailure = \inp -> []

pitem :: Parser Char
pitem = \inp -> case inp of 
    [] -> []
    (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]


parse :: Parser a -> Parser a 
--parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]

parse p inp = p inp

{-
combine :: Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser (a,b)
combine p1 p2 = \inp -> p2 t output
    where
        p1 inp = ([


-}
-- firstlast :: Parser (Char,Char)
firstlast = do 
    x <- pitem
    z <- pitem
    y <- pitem
    preturn (x,y)

another = do
    x <- pitem
    y <- pitem
```

Firstlast is supposed to take a string and return the first and third character. Unfortunately, it returns odd values, and it does not accept its type (Parser (Char,Char))

For example,

```
*Main> firstlast "abc"
[(([('a',"bc")],[('a',"bc")]),"abc")]
```

What should happen is:

```
*Main> firstlast "abc"
[("ac",[])]
```

Comment: Did you write scheme before Haskell by chance?

Comment: Also, did you really mean to use the list monad here?

Comment: @jozefg It's not the list monad that's used here, but the `(->) r` monad.

Comment: It looks like you are using Graham Hutton's book (or lecture notes derived from it). Because Graham doesn't want to introduce `newtype`, the presentation in the book isn't proper Haskell. There is a note in the comment at the end of the chapter regarding this and the code on the book's website "corrects" the code in book to be proper Haskell. The answer from kosmikus below also shows how to make the code work with a newtype.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. Jozefg, why do you say that? I have never programmed scheme or lisp although I do like the sound of its simplicity. I have programmed Prolog and Haskell mostly, but I am a novice programmer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please use code that compiles. Your `another` function does not.

### What's the problem?

Your code for `firstlast` and `another` makes use of `do`-notation. And the way you're using `pitem` here, it looks as if you're expecting `Parser` to be a monad. But it isn't, at least not in the way you expect it to be.

There is a monad instance pre-defined which make GHC think that `Parser` is a monad, namely

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
  return = const
  f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

What this instance says is that, for any type `r` the function type `r -> ...` can be considered a monad, namely by distributing the parameter everywhere. So returning something in this monad amounts to producing a value ignoring the parameter of type `r`, and binding a value means that you take `r` and pass it on both to the left and right computation.

This is not what you want for a parser. The input string will be distributed to all computations. So each `pitem` will operate on the original input string. Furthermore, as

```
pitem :: String -> [(Char, String)]
```

the result of your monadic computation will be of type `[(Char, String)]`, so `x` and `y` are both of this type. That's why you get the result

```
[(([('a',"bc")],[('a',"bc")]),"abc")]
```

You're calling `pitem` three times on the same input string. You're putting two results in a pair, and you're `preturn`-ing the whole thing.

### How to fix it?

You need to define your own monad instance for the `Parser` type. You cannot do that directly, because `Parser` is a type synonym, and type synonyms cannot be partially applied,
so you cannot write

```
instance Monad Parser where
  ...
```

Instead, you have to wrap `Parser` in a new datatype or newtype:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a, String)] }
```

This gives you a constructor `Parser` and a function `parse` to convert between the unwrapped and wrapped parser types:

```
Parser :: String -> [(a, String)] -> Parser a
parse  :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
```

This implies you'll have to adapt your other functions. For example, `preturn` becomes

```
preturn :: a -> Parser a 
preturn t = Parser (\inp -> [(t,inp)])
```

Change `pfailure` and `pitem` similarly. Then, you have to define the `Monad` instance:

```
instance Monad Parser where
  return = preturn
  (>>=)  = ... -- to be completed by you
```

The function `(>>=)` is not contained in your code above. You'll want to implement the behaviour that the input is passed to the first parser, and for every result of that, the result and the remaining input are passed to the second argument of `(>>=)`. Once this is done, a call to `parse firstlast "abc"` will have the following result:

```
[(('a','c'),"")]
```

which isn't quite what you want in your question, but I believe it's what you're actually after.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer but I have absolutely no idea what a monad is so I don't really understand you. I gather that a monad has some way of taking a function and returning its arguments? (like taking f a then returning a)

Comment: A monad is a parameterized type (such as 'Parser') that supports two specific operations, one being a way to lift a value into the type, exactly your `preturn :: a -> Parser a`, and another which is typically called bind and written `(>>=)`, but you could also call it `pbind :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b`. This allows you to combine two parsers into one in such a way that the second may depend on the result of the first. Without `pbind`, you have no way to combine parsers. You use `do`-syntax (which translates to monad operations), but this can't magically guess what you mean.